# Commit from another contributor onto my Pull Request

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pull-request, git-fork

I couldn't find the solution anywhere on Google, so here's my question.

Onto my favorite GitHub project, I did a Pull Request from my fork's topic branch including new functionality that will be merged in future releases.

Is there a way for another contributor to commit onto my Pull Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your pull request will be automatically updated if you add more commits to that branch, so if you accept a pull request/merge others' commits onto that branch, then yes, that's how another contributor can commit onto your pull request.